# problem with javascript getElementById that is hidden

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that will return a user id for a website i am registered for. When logged into the website there is a piece of code as follows:

```
<input id="memberID" name="00V85345345343ugFFC" type="hidden" value="3959721"/>
```

This is the JavaScript i am using but it doesnt do anything. AmI doing something wrong here?

```
javascript:alert("Your member ID is\n"+document.getElementById("memberID")[0].value);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns a `HTMLElement` or `null` if no element was found matching that ID.

Because element ID's are supposed to be unique, it makes no sense to return an Array; a maximum of one element should be matched.

```
javascript:alert("Your member ID is\n"+document.getElementById("memberID").value);
```

`document.getElementsByTagName` however, for example (note the plural of elements, rather than element), returns an array of elements; as it makes perfect sense to have more than one element of the same tag in a page.

```
var divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (divElements.length) {
    var firstElement = divElements[0];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

getElementById returns single element, not array of elements.

So this:

```
getElementById("memberID")[0].value
```

Must become just:

```
getElementById("memberID").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby this will help abit in cleaning up that error:

http://p-xr.com/jquery-like-getelementbyid-in-1-line-of-code/